# Interior $H^2$ regularity - inequalities over regions $U$ and $W \subset U$

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

This question is a direct continuation of my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/893177/interior-h2-regularity-applying-cauchys-inequality-with-epsilon). However, this one is requesting only for a relatively simple explanation.

Note: $W \subset U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

On page 330 of PDE Evans, 2nd edition, it says:

> Now Theorem 3(i) in §5.82 implies
>   \begin{align}
> \int_u |v|^2 \, dx &\le C \int_U |D(\zeta^2 D_k^h u)|^2 \, dx \\
> &\le C \int_W |D_k^h U|^2 + \zeta^2 |D_k^h Du|^2 \, dx \\
> &\le C \int_U |Du|^2 + \zeta^2 |D_k^h Du|^2 \, dx
> \end{align}

For the second inequality, I have a feeling they used the triangle inequality with exponent $p$ of $(a+b)^p \le 2^p(a^p+b^p)$, for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $1 \le p < \infty$. However, how can we suddenly change from integrating over the region $U$ to over the subregion $W$, upon applying the triangle inequality with exponent $p$?

Comment: @cookie....can you teach me sobolev spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at your previous question it seems like $\zeta$ is nonnegative and  supported in W, so that's why you can do it, it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\zeta$ is supported in $W$ (assuming the same notation as in your other question), also $D(\zeta^2 D_k^h u)$ is supported in $W$.